# NullPointerException while all values are non null

Tags: kotlin

in my class `init` a property is set to the value of a parameter. Neither the parameter nor its property is null but there is a null pointer exception

```
init {
    creationDate = owner.network.currentDate
}
```

you can try it [online here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/6mf3canm1qjek8ld279roikme2/qgls3oakbatqcdl336off9kamd)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Vault.&amp;lt;init&amp;gt;(Vault.kt:13)
    at NetworkProductionVault.&amp;lt;init&amp;gt;(Vault.kt:65)
    at Snc_tokenKt.main(snc-token.kt:13)
```

Comment: pls, create a minimal working example that reproduces the given problem, this is not a code review or debugging site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this to `init` in `Vault.kt` in your example:

```
if (owner == null) println("owner is null")
```

And it is indeed null.

I think the reason is because you've declared this property (`owner`) as `open`, but you're referring to it when initializing the superclass. So it's going to be null at that point because the superclass will try to get the value from the subclass, but the subclass won't have been initialized yet. This is explained in a bit more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179841/beginner-question-inheritance-why-isnt-my-age-constructor-parameter-used/53185727#53185727).